# Bluetooth connect no longer works on iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth

I am the developer of Rock Paper Missiles, a strategy game that was released to the App Store about a month ago. This weekend I got my new iPhone 5s, and noticed a critical problem with the bluetooth local multiplayer in the game. The "searching for devices" alert no longer appears, but this only happens on iPhone 5s. My game isn't the only one that does this. Another local bluetooth game, Zombieville USA 2, also has this problem. In their case however, it's worse. The app freezes when you try to connect.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or do I need to wait for Apple to fix iOS 7? Could it be an iOS issue? It seems to only happen on this specific hardware.

Comment: I would check on the Apple Dev Forums to see if this is a common problem. I do know the iOS 7 Bluetooth stack has changed. Have you checked the WWDC 2013 videos about the new stack? Sorry I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Any luck?  I'm having the same issue.  Broken on the 5s, but works on older devices.  Even though they are all running iOS 7.  There is the new [Multipeer Connectivity Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328-CH1-SW1) but that doesn't explain why this broke.

Comment: Still have no idea why this is happening, sorry. I've been looking into this all week.

Comment: Does your code generate any warnings in XCode when you build it? Have you built it against iOS7 with a Deployment Target of 7.0?

Comment: I'm also having the exact same issue. There is a discussion about this on the iOS Dev Forums but no answer so far. The only device affected is the iPhone 5S! -- We need to maintain compatibility with iOS6 so we can't migrate to the Multipeer Connectivity framework. Any new findings on this?

Comment: These are the errors. http://i.imgur.com/4ohI1XM.png